# Access and modify default tv font sizes through Samsung SDK

Tags: sdk, font-size, samsung-smart-tv, subtitle

Is there any way to change the maximum subtitle font size (for movies playback) of a samsung smart tv through its SDK?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a little old but I had the same issue a few days ago and wanted to share my experience. I'm guessing you're referring to the closed-captioning feature on the TV. If your video has 608 captions, then unfortunately you can't change it. But if it has the newer 708 captions, then you can change the font size, color and all.

Hope this helps.

Comment: hi, captions you mean is subtitle embedded inside the video or external .smi subtitle file?